# Javascript object literal return function as key not working

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I have a function that receives two parameters, and returns an Object literal, but the keys are also functions (`toaster.pop`):

```
    _self.popCategoryResponse = (msg, param) => ({
        'SAME_CATEGORY_NAME': toaster.pop({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Ops!',
            body: $translate.instant('categorynameexistsin',
                {name: param.name}),
            bodyOutputType: 'trustHtml'
        }),

        'SAME_ROOT_CATEGORY_NAME': toaster.pop({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Ops!',
            body: $translate.instant('categorynameexistsinroot'),
            bodyOutputType: 'trustHtml'
        }),

        'BLANK_CATEGORY_NAME': toaster.pop({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Ops!',
            body: $translate.instant('categorynameisblank'),
            bodyOutputType: 'trustHtml'
        }),

        'NEW_CATEGORY_CREATED': toaster.pop({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Ok!',
            body: $translate.instant('categorycreated',
                {name: param.name}),
            bodyOutputType: 'trustHtml'
        }),

        'CATEGORY_REMOVED': toaster.pop({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Ok!',
            body: $translate.instant('categoryremoved',
                {name: param.name}),
            bodyOutputType: 'trustHtml'
        })
    })[msg];
```

I have two problems with this approach:

1. Now I am calling this function with `_self.popCategoryResponse('BLANK_CATEGORY_NAME', node)`, but it is not only calling the function for the key `'BLANK_CATEGORY_NAME'`, but also for the other keys.
2. Sometimes I am not using the `param` parameter as you can see in some keys, so is it correct to call my function somewhat like `_self.popCategoryResponse('BLANK_CATEGORY_NAME', null)`?

Comment: Your *keys* are strings. `toaster.pop` is used for the *values* of the object literal.

Comment: Yes, `toaster.pop()` is called for every value that is created on the object, those are not *functions*. Wrap them in a function expression if you don't want to execute the code right away but store a function in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding here seems to be that your object's keys point to *functions* that are evaluated upon access. This is not the case. Every time `popCategoryResponse` is called, you are creating an object whose keys are *the result of evaluating* `toaster.pop(...)`.

Here is an example if you want to convince yourself of that:

```js
const toaster = [1,2,3,4,5]

// you expect to 'pop' once
// when in fact, it 'pop's three times
const fn = key => ({
  a: toaster.pop(),
  b: toaster.pop(),
  c: toaster.pop()
})[key]

fn('a')
console.log(toaster) // -> [1, 2]

fn()
console.log(toaster) // -> []
```

Here is a solution:

```js
const toaster = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// now the keys are functions which you can invoke to pop only once
const fn = key => {
  const value = {
    a: () => toaster.pop(),
    b: () => toaster.pop(),
    c: () => toaster.pop()
  }[key]

  if (typeof value === 'function') {
    value()
  }
}

fn('a')
console.log(toaster) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]

fn()
console.log(toaster) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Although I would suggest considering another approach if you have a function mutating an out of scope variable (`toaster`). At least consider passing it in to `popCategoryResponse` for testability.

Comment: I wrapped it in a function as said: `SAME_CATEGORY_NAME: () => toaster.pop({ // more code`, but surprinsingly it is not calling any function now, and I am passing the right string, like `_self.popCategoryResponse('SAME_CATEGORY_NAME', node)`.

Comment: Found it! Wasn't calling it as a function anyway: `})[msg]` should be `})[msg]()`